# How to check if an object is nil in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I know this seems pretty basic but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I have the following code.

```
Target *t = self.skill.target;


if (![t isEqual:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"Not nil");
}
```

I tried this and it comes up as not nil everytime which is great except for when `t` should actually be nil. I even tried putting  variation into the code like so and my t is still coming up as not nil for some reason. Am I doing something wrong? :\

```
Target *t = self.skill.target;
t = nil;

if (![t isEqual:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"Not nil");
}
```

Comment: why is the `if (t == nil) { ... }` not good?

Comment: I keep getting false even if `t` is nil

Comment: that is not really possible scenario, you probably misinterpret something seriously.

Comment: You can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626469/3378413

Comment: Looking at the answers, I'm thinking if the value can be revealed through the debugger, too. Am I getting this wrong or are both ways legit?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it normally just by checking the object itself. There is also a good explanation on [NSHipster for NSNull](http://nshipster.com/nil/).

```
if( myObject ){
    // do something if object isn't nil
} else {
    // initialize object and do something
}
```

otherwise just use

```
if( myObject == nil ){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Target *t = self.skill.target;
t = nil;

if (t) {
    NSLog(@"t is Not nil");
}
if (!t) {
    NSLog(@"t is nil");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` operation checks nillable so this should works:

```
Target *t = self.skill.target;
if (t) {
    NSLog(@"Not nil");
}else{
    NSLog(@"nil");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5914886/1806873) answer says:

> Any message to nil will return a result which is the equivalent to 0 for the type requested. Since the 0 for a boolean is NO, that is the result.

So, a `nil` object is special. you can't compare it using the `isEqual` method. you should compare it without sending it a message, like this:

```
if (t) 
{
}
```

or simply:

```
if (t != nil)
{
}
```