# what matches with default string in ios

Tags: nsstring

```
NSString * a = @"";
```

I have taken this empty (or default) string and tried to check whether it is equal to nil, Nil or NULL but it returns NO. can anyone explain me in detail

```
if ([a isEqual:NULL]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }

if ([a isEqual:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }

if ([a isEqual:Nil]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code `NSString * a = @"";` creates a new NSString. It is exactly the same as using `[[NSString alloc] init]`.

If you want nil, you have to do like this `NSString* a = nil`.

In Objective-C nil is used to create pointers to nothing, so don't use NULL of Nil. If you wan't more information about nil/Nil/NULL [this article](http://nshipster.com/nil/) explains it all.

**Edit** for answering question in first comment:

```
NSString *fileName = nil; 
NSLog(@"%@",[fileName isEqual:nil]?@"S":@"N"); 
NSLog(@"%@",[fileName isEqualTo:nil]?@"S":@"N"); 
NSLog(@"%@",[fileName isEqualToString:nil]?@"S":@"N");
```

In all of these cases your NSString is nil. In objective-C it is allowed to use methods on a nil object, but it wil always return a default value which is 0. 0 for a boolean type is NO. That is why you always get 'N'. It is a bit weird in this case because you're comparing nil to nil, but that's how it is. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914845/sending-isequal-to-nil-always-returns-no) goes little bit more into detail

If you want to check if an object is nil do something like this:

```
if (filename) {
    // Do something with filename
} else {
    // filename is nil
}
```

Comment: can you please go through this NSString *fileName = nil;        
        NSLog(@"%@",[fileName isEqual:nil]?@"S":@"N");
        NSLog(@"%@",[fileName isEqualTo:nil]?@"S":@"N");
        NSLog(@"%@",[fileName isEqualToString:nil]?@"S":@"N"); I have tried all these but the result in all cases is "N" fileName is assigned with nil.... but why I'm getting "N"???????